# Cypress installation fails with error App could not be downloaded

Tags: reactjs, npm, proxy, cypress

I am trying to install cypress in a machine under corporate firewall. I get below error on npm install

App could not be downloaded

Steps followed to resolve this error:

1.set http and https proxy in the environment variable by running the below commands

set HTTP_PROXY ='[proxy url]'
set HTTPS_PROXY = '[proxy url]'

This step didn't resolve the problem

2. set CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY='local path for cypress.zip'
   npm install cypress

This step installed the cypress successfully

I want to give the cypress.tgz file path available in the company nexus repo
directly in the CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY env variable.

If I try this, it throws error in installation step again with message 'unable to get local issuer certificate'

Question - can I give .tgz file for cypress install binary variable?. If so, how can I directly refer the nexus repo url for it?

Please let me know in-case any other options are also available for cypress installation.

Answer (score 0):

'unable to get local issuer certificate' means that you are using https. Try to use http instead of https like: http://link-to-your-repo-in-nexus.